# Mixing std::tr1::shared_ptr with std::function / std::bind causes compiler errors with newer gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, tr1

I need to use some old legacy code which uses `std::tr1::shared_ptr`. The header that I need to include has both `#include <tr1/memory>` and `#include <tr1/functional>`. In my code I want to use `std::function` and `std::bind`, since our compiler supports these.

This works fine with gcc 4.6.3 and 4.7.3. In 4.9.2, 5.1.x and 5.2.0 this results in a compiler error. It seems to happen due to the `<tr1/functional>`-include.

I wrote a small example that reproduce this problem:

```
#include <tr1/memory>
#include <functional>
#include <tr1/functional>

struct Foo {
    void test(std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> i) {}
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    std::function<void(std::tr1::shared_ptr<int>)> func = std::bind(&Foo::test, f, std::placeholders::_1);

    return 0;
}
```

gcc-4.6.3, without `#include <tr1/functional>`, compiles OK. Tested on my local machine.

gcc-4.6.3, with `#include <tr1/functional>`, compiles OK. Tested on my local machine.

gcc-5.1, without `#include <tr1/functional>`, compiles OK: http://ideone.com/XrkAXT

gcc-5.1, with `#include <tr1/functional>`, compiler error: http://ideone.com/sRWQLn

I'm not using any `std::tr1::function` or `std::tr1::bind` at all, and the only thing I use from the legacy code is a `std::tr1::shared_ptr` object.

Why does the `#include <tr1/functional>` affect the non-tr1 `std::function` / `std::bind`? Or what's happening here?

Edit: According to [GNU C++ Library Manual, Chapter 3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_headers.html): "*A special case of the second rule is the mixing of TR1 and C++11 facilities. It is possible (although not especially prudent) to include both the TR1 version and the C++11 version of header in the same translation unit*"

Comment: Clang is somewhat more useful and reports an [ambiguity](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42b7d781e2829fb7). I'm going to guess ADL.

Comment: isn't that because you included both functional and tr1/functional?

Comment: is the tr1/functional from boost?

Comment: @sop No. (too short comment)

Comment: What is the old code that uses tr1? I think it should be ported to c++11, that has no more the tr1. The tr1 does not exists anymore in C++11. I use just memory (not tr1/memory), functional (not tr1/functional). I thnk you should replace all the std::tr1:: by std::. Or are you using 2 compilers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a change in the standard that requires the implementation to constrain `std::function`'s constructor so that it's not convertible from everything under the sun, but only from actual callables, so libstdc++ computes the return type with:

```
template<typename _Functor>
using _Invoke = decltype(__callable_functor(std::declval<_Functor&>())
                         (std::declval<_ArgTypes>()...) );
```

and uses it in the SFINAE. Expression SFINAE means that if the call expression doesn't compile, the converting constructor is removed from the overload set.

The problem is with that `__callable_functor`. Its job is to wrap pointer-to-members so that they can be used with the normal function call syntax. And it's a reserved name so nobody else should be using it...well, except other components of the standard library. We have `std::__callable_functor` in `<functional>` and `std::tr1::__callable_functor` in `<tr1/functional>`. And because `std::tr1` is an associated namespace (thanks to the use of `std::tr1::shared_ptr<int>` in the signature of `Foo::test`), you end up with an ambiguity.

**Edit**: reported as [bug 68995](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68995).